# Binary trees syntax error

Tags: ocaml

I don't have any idea wht I can't define a bin_tree like this :

```
type 'a bin_tree = Node of { data : 'a ; left : 'a bin_tree; right : 'a bin_tree; } | Leaf
```

Merlin tells me : error inside type, expecting _

Comment: what does the compiler say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using inline records, a new language feature that has only been available since version 4.03.0.

Since 4.03.0, it has been possible to do the following:

```
type t = A of { ... } | B
```

Before 4.03.0, you had to define the record type separately:

```
type t = A of r | B and r = { ... }
```

You have to either rewrite your code accordingly or switch your OCaml installation to version 4.03.0 or later.

Comment: thanks , this wasn't mentioned in my lecture slides :)

Answer (score 0):

The record type is not defined yet - and the record definition is related to bin_tree and so you have to define them jointly, try :

> ```
>  type 'a pp = {data : 'a; left: 'a bin_tree; right : 'a bin_tree} and
>       'a bin_tree = Node of 'a pp | Leaf ;;
> ```